# Non overlapping data in train test validation split python

Tags: python, validation, testing, split, training-data

I'm trying to create a function for some deep learning issues for satellite images classification. I have searched through a lot of libraries and I haven't found my needs I tried this sikit-learn but I feel that it is not what I need

Any hint for a specialised function that I may not see?

Answer (score 0):

The `sklearn train_test_split` seems to fit all your needs.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: it doesnt ensure that the sets are unique. it just splits

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you give me a bit more explanation about what you mean by "unique data in each group and no redundant ones"?

Comment: I mean that for example if my data are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 
during the spliting i need to have '1'in just one set (test or train or validation) same for "2"

Comment: I have not to find 5 for example in the testing and the validation set

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You can use the permutation array on the X and y data separately if you like.

```
num_tr, num_va = int(len(data)*0.5), int(len(data)*0.2)
perm = np.random.permutation(len(data))
tr_data = data[perm[:num_tr]]
va_data = data[perm[num_tr:num_tr+num_va]]
te_data = data[perm[num_tr+num_va:]]
```

Comment: I think this takes the data as it is read and splits it by part . It does not shuffle it or take sets from different parts?

Comment: I wish that the function be something like wat I said to mantain the form and the constraint of the data I provided

Comment: I believe I don't understand your problem then. Do you want the data shuffled or ordered? If you want both, what should be shuffled and what should remain in order?